# Display results according to calendar weeks in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection named Bookings

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca982d219fee6f00e631a0"),
    "price" : 45.9,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-04T20:12:29.117Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca990b219fee6f00e631a1"),
    "price" : 45.9,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-04T20:16:11.925Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcab925a912a2064fe7b916"),
    "price" : 45.9,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-04T22:33:09.958Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcab938a912a2064fe7b917"),
    "price" : 45.9,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-04T22:33:28.641Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcab94aa912a2064fe7b918"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-04T22:33:46.118Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcb73e0e396cf18e6141dc6"),
    "price" : 45.9,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-05T11:49:52.544Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcb73eee396cf18e6141dc7"),
    "price" : 45.9,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-05T11:50:06.914Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcbee785ef206248fa9513e"),
    "price" : 35.7,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-05T20:32:56.508Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fcbf0045ef206248fa9513f"),
    "price" : 2047.66,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-05T20:39:32.369Z")
}
```

I need to display the data according to a week and collective price for that week. If I use aggregation pipeline, It would only give me the range of dates on which booking is made.

```
{$group: {
    _id: {
                                   
        $week: "$createdAt"                          
    },
   
    start_date: {$min: "$createdAt"},
    end_date: {$max: "$createdAt"}                               
}}
```

Suppose the previous week started from `14-06-21` and ended on `20-06-21`
Instead, I want a result which would actually include `start_date` as `14-06-21` and `end_date` as `20-06-21`, and if no earning is made it would be 0 otherwise the total price in a given week and so on for other group of weeks for whole year or month accordingly.

Comment: Is your aggregation pipeline working? Please clarify what's problem!

Comment: mongodb will not provide week's start and end date, you need to get start/end date from week number from your client side language.

Comment: h-sifat, aggregation pipline is working fine, but the data I want is 
{
"week":1,
"earnings":0,
"startDate":"01-01-21",
"endDate":"07-01-21"
},
{
"week":2,
"earnings":23,
"startDate":"08-01-21",
"endDate":"-15-01-21"
},

Comment: turivishal, So how can I categorize my data into a week, as I mentioned in the comment. It would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: I have a workaround solution, let me know if you are still looking for an answer

Comment: hhharsha36 that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Added an answer, see if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can categorize total price by week number using `$week` operator, but it is hard to get the week's start date and end date in MongoDB, I would suggest you to get start date and end date from the week number in your client-side language.

- `$group` by `createdAt`'s week using `$week` operator and get total price by `$sum`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $week: "$createdAt" },
      totalPrice: { $sum: "$price" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZFFjoTqkoj5)

Answer (score 0):

For fetching the start day of a week, you can make use of the `$dateToString` operator and pass the `%g` and `%v` in `format` which represents ISO Year and Week of the year respectively.

Similarly, add `518400000` (6 days in milliseconds) to the start date of the week to get the end date.

Also, these two operations will only work inside the `_id` field of the `$group` stage, so parse the sub-object of the `_id` key to get the required data values. The `weekNo` key is useless for the `$group` stage, but keep it if it's required.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "weekNo": {
          $week: "$createdAt"
        },
        "start_date": {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": {
              "$dateToString": {
                "date": "$createdAt",
                "format": "%G/%V",
              },
            },
            "format": "%G/%V"
          }
        },
        "end_date": {
          "$add": [
            {
              "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": {
                  "$dateToString": {
                    "date": "$createdAt",
                    "format": "%G/%V",
                  },
                },
                "format": "%G/%V"
              }
            },
            518400000,
          ],
        },
      },
      totalPrice: {
        $sum: "$price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OmOOF2s0Rze)